# How to get the hard coded string as output in views_php module

Tags: 7, views

I am using quiz module.

I am creating a view which has field which shows the status of the quiz. If the user score is greater than pass rate, the field should display "pass" else "fail". How to achieve this.

I used views php module to do this. But, I'm confused between **Value code** and **Output code**.

Can anybody provide some pointers?

Answer (score 1):

**Value Code** : The value of the Field.

**Output Code** : The php code that you wish to execute for getting the output for that field.